# Dart Double to String is sometimes 5900.0 sometimes 5900

Tags: flutter, dart

Based on Flutter 1.26.0-17.8.pre Dart SDK 2.10.4 (from Dart Pad)

```
void main() {
  double num = 5900.0;
  if (num.toString() == "5900.0") {
    print(true);
  } else {
    print(false);
  }
}
```

Evaluate **false**,

Based on **Flutter (Channel unknown, 1.26.0-17.8.pre, on macOS 11.0.1 20B29 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)**

The same code above evaluates **true**

The documentation does not say anything about which one is correct https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/double/toString.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why 2.0 (the number 2.0) is double and int at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54827376/why-2-0-the-number-2-0-is-double-and-int-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 2):

This is related to compilation to javascript. Javascript does not have a distinction between floating-point and integral data types. There are just "numbers". When you run in DartPad you're compiling to javascript and losing the typing information from that `.0`.

Running in the VM does not have this behavior as there is a distinction between the types.

If you believe this is a real issue, you can report it, but I believe I've seen something [similar](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/1533) before already and it will be dismissed. As you mentioned, the `toString` documentation makes no claims about its exact output, just that it can be parsed back.

Additionally, do not use reserved keywords, e.g. `num`, as variable names.